# Pandas: Conditionally Selecting Columns to perform Calculation based on Header of another Column

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause, string-matching

My dataframe looks like this:

```
(1, 2)  (1, 3)  (1, 4)  (1, 5)  (1, 6)  (1, 7)  (1, 8)  (1, 9)  (1, 10) (1, 11) ... 2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11
0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   ... 0.612544    0.727393    0.366578    0.631451    0.722980    0.772853    0.964982    0.549801    0.406692    0.798083
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0.583228    0.698729    0.343934    0.602037    0.694230    0.745422    0.954682    0.521298    0.382381    0.771640
2   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   ... 0.481291    0.593353    0.271028    0.498949    0.588807    0.641602    0.901779    0.424495    0.303309    0.669657
3   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   ... 0.583228    0.698729    0.343934    0.602037    0.694230    0.745422    0.954682    0.521298    0.382381    0.771640
4   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   ... 0.612544    0.727393    0.366578    0.631451    0.722980    0.772853    0.964982    0.549801    0.406692    0.798083
```

where i have column headers with a tuple like `(1, 2)` and column headers that are a single element, like `1`. I want to perform a calculation on the tuple columns based on the columns that have the elements of that tuple. For example, with the tuple `(1, 2)`, I want to retrieve the columns `1` and `2`, multiply them together, then subtract the result from the column `(1, 2)`.

The solution that I thought of was to create (55) new columns that perform the first calculation from the columns that contain only a single element (e.g. `1` or `2`), and then do some sort of identity match using the `.where()` and `all()` statements. However, this seems rather computationally inefficient since I'd be making a whole other set of data, rather than performing the calculation directly on the tuple column. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is faster, but here's a solution without needing where()/all()

```
import pandas as pd


# create some sample data
arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=[('a', 'b'), ('c','d'), ('a', 'd'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

# get all tuple headers
tuple_columns = [col for col in df.columns if isinstance(col, tuple)]

# put the results into a list of series and concat into a DataFrame
results = pd.concat([df[col] - df[col[0]] * df[col[1]] for col in tuple_columns], axis=1)

# rename the columns
results.columns = tuple_columns
```